# How can I calculate the norm of this linear functional on $\mathbb R^3$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, normed-spaces

I've been trying to calculate the norm of $\phi\colon \mathbb R^3\rightarrow \mathbb R$ defined by $\phi(x,y,z)=1.2x-0.6y$.

I really don't know how to this.
I did note that $\phi(-2y,y,z)=-3y$, therefore  $|\phi(-2y,y,z)|\leq (3/\sqrt5)\|(-2y,y,z)\|$ meaning that $\|f\|\leq 3/\sqrt5$. my assumption that the other inequallity is also true, but I can't prove it.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\|\varphi\|=\max_{\|v\|=1}\|\varphi(v)\|=\max_{x^2+y^2+z^2=1}|1.2x-0.6y|={3\over \sqrt{5}}$$

You can get the last equality several ways, one of which is by using Lagrange Multipliers on the constrained optimization problem. This will work when your functional is more complicated.

Here, though, you could note that since $\varphi$ is independent of $z$, then the constraint says $y=\pm\sqrt{1-x^2}$ so that $$|1.2x-0.6y|=|1.2x\mp 0.6\sqrt{1-x^2}\,|,$$ which is maximized when $x=\pm 2/\sqrt{5}\implies y=\mp 1/\sqrt{5}$, and the maximum is $3/\sqrt{5}$.

Looking at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/290289/52893) might help solidify the geometry of this concept.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was very useful. And the geometric concept is very nice as well. A question to make myself understand better: if the norm on $\mathbb R^3$ was not $||_2$, but say for example $||_1$ (and so the constraint wouldn't be as nice as here) - what could one try to do? Lagrange Multiplier? Any more methods that I could read about?

Comment: Yes, in general if you need $\max_{\|v\|_V=1}\|\varphi(v)\|_W$, I would translate $\|\varphi(v)\|_W$ into an algebraic expression in the components of $v$ and do the same for the constraint $\|v\|_V=1$. Then you will have a constrained optimization problem (in the components of $v$) which you can approach using Lagrange Multipliers.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the vector
$${\bf a}:=\left({6\over5},\ -{3\over5}, \ 0\right)\ .$$
Then $\phi({\bf r})={\bf a}\cdot {\bf r}$ and therefore $$\bigl|\phi({\bf r})\bigr|\leq |{\bf a}|\>|{\bf r}|={3\over\sqrt{5}}\>|{\bf r}|\qquad\forall\> {\bf r}\in{\mathbb R}^3\ .$$ 
This  proves $$\|\phi\|\leq {3\over\sqrt{5}}\ .$$ (Note that your proof of this fact is not watertight since you only considered "special" vectors ${\bf r}$.)

On the other hand, $\phi({\bf a})=|{\bf a}|^2={3\over\sqrt{5}}|{\bf a}|$, which implies $\|\phi\|\geq{3\over\sqrt{5}}$.

All in all we have proven that $$\|\phi\|={3\over\sqrt{5}}\ .$$
When the euclidean norm in ${\mathbb R}^3$ is replaced by the $\|\cdot\|_1$-norm we can argue as follows: The unit sphere with respect to this norm is the octahedron
$$O:\quad |x|+|y|+|z|=1\ .$$
The linear functional $\phi$ takes its maximum on $O$ at one of the six vertices (this is a fundamental principle of linear programming), and a quick check shows that this is the vertex $(1,0,0)$. It follows that
$$\|\phi\|=\phi(1,0,0)=1.2\ .$$

Comment: Thantks a lot, that was very useful. What would you suggest doing if my norm was not $||_2$, so I couldn't use Cauchy-Schwartz like you did here?

Comment: Tell us the norm you want to use, and we shall see what we can do.

Comment: $||_1$, thanks.

Comment: Why must the linear functional take its maximum on one of the vertices?